# Change Cuboid circle button color on runtime

Tags: android

Cuboid circle button is a custom circle button in android (source: [Github Cuboid Circle Button](https://github.com/MuhammadArsalanChishti/Cuboid-Circle-Button)).

I'm using that button in my app. It works well, but I cannot find a way to change its color programmatically on runtime.

In the class, before `onCreate` I have:

`com.cuboid.cuboidcirclebutton.CuboidButton btnReplayEnd;`

Then in `onCreate`:

`btnReplayEnd = (com.cuboid.cuboidcirclebutton.CuboidButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReplayEnd);`

And in the 'setTheme' method (in the same class):

`btnReplayEnd.setCircle_color(getResources().getColor(R.color‌.replayNormalDark));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**there is no way to change the circler color of** `com.cuboid.cuboidcirclebutton.CuboidButton` programatically **you can only change it via xml using** `app:cub_color="@color/color_03A9F4"`
like this

```
<com.cuboid.cuboidcirclebutton.CuboidButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="No Border"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:cub_border_radius="0dp"
            app:cub_color="@color/color_03A9F4"
            app:cub_fontstyle="fonts/Bellerose.ttf"
            app:cub_hover_color="#00BFFF1"
            />
```